# Input HTML version of Facebook Debugger

Tags: facebook, debugging

I'm trying to find a version of [Facebook Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/) which allows me to submit HTML to discover what information is shared on Facebook.

I can only seem to find the original Facebook Debugger tool which requests a URL instead of a code snippet.

Has anyone seen one of these before?

Comment: That doesn’t exist, at least not officially from Facebook.

Comment: Why don't you just submit a URL via the graph api and get the details of the previewed elements from the response JSON?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concluded that HTML input version of Facebook Debugger *does not exist* anywhere on the web.

Was trying to locate this facility to test changes in code without having to re-deploy a page to a live environment.

Advanced settings in Facebook Debugger display what og:image is currently targeting when og:image is *not* set within the Meta Data, and therefore I was able to discover that SVGs are ignored, and then the highest resolution image is then targeted and then descends in order of image size.